# Q: Magento2 : upgrading from magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.3,

Tags: magento-2.3, magento2.4

I encounter a problem after upgrading magento from 2.3.4 to 2.4.3

php -v : 7.4
composer -V : Composer version 2.2.12

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento cache:clean

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/page_cache/*

rm -rf generated/code/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

all the steps where good until i reached this step : php bin/magento setup:di:compile

```
    Compilation was started.
    Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 151.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Mirasvit\Report\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getColumns($component)
 must be compatible with 
Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getColumns(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface $component): array in /var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/Mirasvit/Report/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php
 on line 53
```

have anyone face similar issue when upgrading ?

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-migrate-magento-2-3-to-2-4/

Answer (score 1):

As per your issue I would suggest you please disabled all third party extension while you upgrading Magento core libraries. once Magento core libraries updated you can update one by one your third party extension's then i hope everything will be working fine.

Still if you have any issue please let us know.